# Using anonymous Threads in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to use an anonymous thread to update a simple label inside of a panel on a form, doing an "animate" end dots, but it isn't working. I'm new to working with threads, and your help will be very useful.

```pascal
procedure TFormEscolaImpresso.UpdateMsg(AShow: Boolean; AMsg: string);
begin
  lbMsg.Caption := AMsg;
  pnMsg.Visible := AShow;
  pnMsg.Update;

  if AShow then
  begin
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      procedure
      begin
        TThread.ForceQueue(TThread.CurrentThread,
          procedure
          begin
            while pnMsg.Visible do
            begin
              lbMsg.Caption := string(lbMsg.Caption).Replace('...', '');

              pnMsg.Update;
              lbMsg.Caption := lbMsg.Caption + '.';

              pnMsg.Update;
              lbMsg.Caption := lbMsg.Caption + '..';
              Sleep(2000);

              pnMsg.Update;
              lbMsg.Caption := lbMsg.Caption + '...';
              Sleep(2000);
            end
          end)
      end).Start;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You are creating a background thread, but all it does is telling the foreground thread to do things. Hence, in effect, nothing is being done in the background at all! You really shouldn't be using a thread here, since you only want to update the GUI at regular intervals. Use a timer.

Comment: But the timer will not affect some loading process?

Comment: Just drop a timer on your form and write `procedure TForm7.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := 'Working' + StringOfChar('.', Timer1.Tag);
  Timer1.Tag := Succ(Timer1.Tag) mod 4;
end;` but like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UyUl.png

Comment: No it will not.

Comment: Or, `TThread.Queue()` if you don't want to block the worker thread while the main thread is updating the UI. Also, `TThread.ForceQueue()` in meant to be used in the main thread, not in a worker thread. `TThread.Queue()` executes the procedure immediately if called in the main thread, whereas `TThread.ForceQueue()` allows the main thread to queue the procedure instead. `TThread.Queue()` and `TThread.ForceQueue()` behave the same when called in a worker thread.

Answer (score 5):

You are queuing your entire worker procedure to run in the main thread, not leaving anything for the anonymous thread to do.  You should break up the logic so that *only* the UI access is synchronized with the main thread, not any of the non-UI work (ie, the sleeps), for example:

```pascal
var
  MyThread: TThread;

procedure TFormEscolaImpresso.UpdateMsg(AShow: Boolean; AMsg: string);
begin
  lbMsg.Caption := AMsg;
  pnMsg.Visible := AShow;

  if AShow then
  begin
    MyThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      procedure
      begin
        while not TThread.CheckTerminated do
        begin
          TThread.Queue(nil,
            procedure
            begin
              lbMsg.Caption := lbMsg.Caption.Replace('...', '');
            end);
          Sleep(2000);
          if TThread.CheckTerminated then Exit;

          TThread.Queue(nil,
            procedure
            begin
              lbMsg.Caption := lbMsg.Caption + '.';
            end);
          Sleep(2000);
          if TThread.CheckTerminated then Exit;

          TThread.Queue(nil,
            procedure
            begin
              lbMsg.Caption := lbMsg.Caption + '.';
            end);
          Sleep(2000);
          if TThread.CheckTerminated then Exit;

          TThread.Queue(nil,
            procedure
            begin
              lbMsg.Caption := lbMsg.Caption + '.';
            end);
          Sleep(2000);
        end;
      end);
    MyThread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
    MyThread.Start;
  end else
  begin
    if MyThread <> nil then
      MyThread.Terminate;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormEscolaImpresso.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyThread := nil;
end;
```

Alternatively, use a UI timer to update the UI at regular intervals, and leave the worker thread to just performing non-UI work, eg:

```pascal
var
  MyThread: TThread;

procedure TFormEscolaImpresso.UpdateMsg(AShow: Boolean; AMsg: string);
begin
  lbMsg.Caption := AMsg;
  lbMsg.Tag := 0;
  pnMsg.Visible := AShow;
  MyTimer.Enabled := AShow;

  if AShow then
  begin
    MyThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      procedure
      begin
        while not TThread.CheckTerminated do
        begin
          for var i := 1 to 4 do
          begin
            Sleep(2000);
            if TThread.CheckTerminated then Exit;
          end;
        end;
      end);
    MyThread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
    MyThread.Start;
  end else
  begin
    if MyThread <> nil then
      MyThread.Terminate;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormEscolaImpresso.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyThread := nil;
end;

procedure TFormEscolaImpresso.MyTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if lbMsg.Tag = 3 then
  begin
    lbMsg.Caption := lbMsg.Caption.Replace('...', '');
    lbMsg.Tag := 0;
  end else
  begin
    lbMsg.Caption := lbMsg.Caption + '.';
    lbMsg.Tag := lbMsg.Tag + 1;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. I will try one of these ways.

Comment: None worked. I write the code exactly the same of both, but the panel in the form isnt updated.

Comment: @jcaique then you will just have to debug your code to see what is really going on. You likely just didn't apply my examples to your code correctly. What I have shown above should work fine when used properly.